# 'SpeechSynthesisUtterance' is undefined in Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis

I am working on converting a text content to speech in my web pages. I have written code in Javascript using SpeechSynthesisUtterance.
Bt I am getting the following error in Microsoft Edge.

```
 'SpeechSynthesisUtterance' is undefined
```

It is working fine in Chrome and Firefox.
Is there any way that i can resolve it?

Comment: is not supported by microsoft https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesisUtterance